# Error: No module named psycopg2.extensions on Mac

Tags: python, database, django, postgresql, psycopg2

When I try and run django, this is what I get:

```
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python manage.py runserver 8000
Error: No module named psycopg2.extensions

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've found other questions with similar problems but none on a mac and none with solutions that help. I get no other errors and I installed psycopg2. Im working in PyCharm. This is my setting file (or the top part of it at least).

```
ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '---',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '---',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '---',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': 'www.-----.com',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

Comment: You're relying on your system's packages, which causes too many variables.  Go install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper globally, then you can install a controlled copy of python, django, psycopg2, etc  all without sudo, and without worrying how your mac is setup.  That might (likely will?) fix the issue, but if not, at least debugging should be easier.

Comment: How did you install `psycopg2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py#L22), Django makes havy use of psycopg2.extensions module. Further, the extensions module is [oficially contained](https://dndg.it/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=public/psycopg2.git;a=blob;f=lib/extensions.py;h=bb8e3dd68009d6e2dc61c4df213736943ea4cb7c;hb=HEAD) in psycopg2. So, what I think is that you have installed psycopg the wrong way.

Here's the right location of the install page: http://initd.org/psycopg/install/

I recommend you to use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)